# memory leak in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-leaks

i m getting a memory leak...

at this particular statement

```
[item setObject:self.currentTitle forkey:@"title"]; ...
```

i have released the memory at dealloc function for `item` and `curentTitle` is declared as

```
self.currentTitle=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
```

but still showing leaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is your property declared?

If it's declared as `retain`, there you have your memory leak...

```
@property( retain, readwrite ) NSMutableString * self.currentTitle;
```

You should do, in such a case:

```
self.currentTitle = [ [ [ NSMutableString alloc ] init ] autorelease ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the convenience method.
    `self.currentTitle = [NSMutableString string];`